# Get certificate info for a signed app

Tags: macos, osx-gatekeeper

We want to get a Mac Developer ID to sign our app for the [Gatekeeper](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5290). When the user downloads the signed app, can the certificate info (common name, etc.) be displayed somewhere? Or it's for Apple internal use?

Answer (score 1):

It's for Apple internal use. All info about your app my be appearing in app "About panel" and only you decide which info will be appear.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking so. But could you provide the source of this info? Cannot find the confirmation in the official docs...

Comment: "Code signing is used in combination with your App ID, provisioning profile, and entitlements..." None of these elements is not available to the user. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/CodeSigningYourApps/CodeSigningYourApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH23-SW2

Comment: "Used in combination ... to ensure that ..." ≠ "is not displayed anywhere"?

Comment: if the information to be used anywhere else, it would have been stated.